# Conditional replacement if values on a row match

Tags: r, database, loops, replace, conditional-statements

I have to analyze data from an economics experiment.
So I have one database (14 976 obs) that I have divided in two : one for sellers-who are type 1 (7488 obs) and another for buyers who are type 2 (7488 obs) with 212 variables in each.

Here, you have part of the two database :

```
sellers
ID       Gender   Period   Matching group   Group    Type  Overcharging ...
654        1           1            73         1        1      NA
654        1           2            73         1        1      NA
654        1           3            73         1        1      NA
654        1           4            73         1        1      NA 
435        1           1            73         2        1      NA
435        1           2            73         2        1      NA
435        1           3            73         2        1      NA
435        1           4            73         2        1      NA 

buyers
 ID       Gender   Period   Matching group   Group    Type  Overcharging ...
 708        0           1            73         1        2       1
 708        0           2            73         1        2       0
 708        0           3            73         1        2       0
 708        0           4            73         1        2       1   
 546        1           1            73         2        2       0
 546        1           2            73         2        2       0
 546        1           3            73         2        2       1
 546        1           4            73         2        2       0
```

I have many variables like the Overcharging one where informations where put in the buyers rows and not in the sellers ones. So what I'd like to do is to replace this informations in sellers database.

For this I have many informations :
In matching group 73 we know for instance that at period 1 subject 708 was overcharged (the one in group 1). As I know that this men belongs to group 1 and matching group 73, I am able to identify the seller who has overcharged him at period 1 : subject 654 with gender =1.

So, I would like to put overcharging (and some others) buyers values on the sellers data frame to analyze sellers behavior but at the right period, for the right group and the right matching group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
#join both dataframes on common columns
merged_df <- left_join(sellers, buyers, by=c('Period', 'Matching_group', 'Group'))

#find row_index which have missing "Overcharging" in sellers
idx <- which(is.na(merged_df$Overcharging.x))
merged_df[idx, "Overcharging.x"] <- merged_df[idx, "Overcharging.y"]

#drop unwanted columns to have the updated sellers
sellers_updated <- merged_df[,-c(dim(sellers)[2]+1: dim(merged_df)[2])]
colnames(sellers_updated) <- colnames(sellers)
sellers_updated
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I tried your solution and it doesn't work. It creates me more observations than my original database...

Comment: Probably you have multiple records for the combination `Period, Matching_group, Group` in `buyers` dataframe. You can confirm this by `library(dplyr); buyers %>% group_by(Period, Matching_group, Group) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% filter(n > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a merge to get the information you need.

```
# Select the Period, Matching Group, Group and Overcharging columns
# Selection by column ID (2nd, 3rd, 4th, 6th columns)
buyers_merge <- buyers[, c(2,3,4,6)]
# Rename the Overcharging column
names(buyers_merge)[4] <- "Overcharging_Buyers"
# Merge
sellers_merged <- merge(sellers, buyers_merge)
```

Now, if I wrote the code above correctly, this should add the Overcharging_Buyers column to a copy of the sellers table. Because 3 out of 4 column names match, the merge function should automatically merge on those columns and add the non-matching column as a new column. You can then replace the original Overcharging column with the newly added information.

For more information on the merge function, see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html).